# Stored Procedure error in localdb

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

Good Day! I am a newbie in asp.net and sql and I am currently working on a Stored procedure that should insert ORDER_DETAILS according to ORDER_ID. When I first made the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, it was working fine but when I transferred it as localdb in Visual Studio, it suddenly doesn't work anymore. I tried running the stored procedure countless times but it still doesn't work.

I have tables ORDER, ORDER_DETAILS and PRODUCT.

**ORDER TABLE**

Id int

COMPANY_ID int

**ORDER_DETAILS**

Id int,

ORDER_ID int

PRODUCT_ID int

COMPANY_ID int

Other attributes

**PRODUCT**

Id int

COMPANY_ID int

Here is my SP:

> SP_INSERT_ORDER_DETAILS

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_INSERT_ORDER_DETAILS]
 @Product_id int,
 @Quantity_ordered int,
 @Status varchar(10)

AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
 SET NOCOUNT OFF;

 DECLARE @iProduct_id int
 DECLARE @OS_ID int
 DECLARE @OrderId int


 SET @OS_ID = (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('ORDERs'))
 SET @OrderId = @OS_ID
 SET @iProduct_id =@Product_id


 DECLARE @totalCost decimal(18,2) 
 DECLARE @itotalCost decimal(18,2)

 DECLARE @iQuantity_ordered int

  DECLARE @Total_amt_per_item decimal (18,2) 
     DECLARE @iTotal_amt_per_item decimal (18,2)

  DECLARE @Total_wdisc_per_item decimal(18,2)
  DECLARE @iTotal_wdisc_per_item decimal(18,2)

  DECLARE @Disc_amt_per_item decimal(18,2)
  DECLARE @iDisc_amt_per_item decimal(18,2)

  DECLARE @MeasurementId int
  DECLARE @iMeasurementId int

  DECLARE @iStatus varchar(10)

  DECLARE @iCompany_id int


 SET @totalCost = (SELECT PRODUCTs.TOTAL_COST FROM PRODUCTs WHERE PRODUCTs.Id =@iProduct_id)
 SET @itotalCost = @totalCost

 SET @iQuantity_ordered =@Quantity_ordered

 SET @Total_amt_per_item = @itotalCost * @iQuantity_ordered
 SET @iTotal_amt_per_item = @Total_amt_per_item


 SET @Disc_amt_per_item = 0.00
 SET @iDisc_amt_per_item = @Disc_amt_per_item
 SET @Total_wdisc_per_item = @iTotal_amt_per_item - @iDisc_amt_per_item
 SET @iTotal_wdisc_per_item =@Total_wdisc_per_item

 SET @MeasurementId = (SELECT PRODUCTs.MEASUREMENT_ID FROM PRODUCTs WHERE PRODUCTs.Id=@iProduct_id)
 SET @iMeasurementId = @MeasurementId

 SET @iStatus =@Status
 SET @iCompany_id = (SELECT COMPANY_ID FROM ORDERs WHERE Id=@OrderId)


 INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAILS(ORDER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,PAYMENT_ID,QUANTITY_ORDERED, [STATUS],MEASUREMENT_ID,DISC_PER_ITEM,DISC_AMT_PER_ITEM,TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM,TOTAL_WDISC_PER_ITEM,PAYMENT_STATUS_ID,COMPANY_ID)
 VALUES (@OrderId,@iProduct_id,0,@iQuantity_ordered, @iStatus, @iMeasurementId,0.00,@iDisc_amt_per_item,@iTotal_amt_per_item,@iTotal_wdisc_per_item,2,@iCompany_id)


 COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH
```

I'm sure I supplied values for the parameters, but still it returns an error. What am I doing wrong? Hope someone can help me out! Thanks!

Comment: What error it returns?

Comment: btw: avoid the `sp_` prefix. This is reserved...

Comment: @Arulkumar It does not execute the SP properly. When I run the SP, it returns -6 value.

Comment: @Shnugo It's not reserved, but it can have performance implications.

Comment: You have a number of things going on here that are less than ideal. First and foremost. Get rid of that awful try catch. You have an anti-pattern there I call try/squelch. You are not handling errors there, you are suppressing them. You have an error and you don't even know what it is. Let the error happen so you can debug it. And why do you have so many variables here?

Comment: @Shnugo noted. Will change that.

Comment: You should also just not insert the identity value instead of trying to capture what it most likely will be and inserting it. I suspect you will find (once you get rid of that catch block) that the error is that you can't insert an explicit value for an identity unless identity_insert is on. If you try to do use an explicit value like that you run the risk of concurrency issues. Just let identity do it's thing and don't try to provide a value for it.

Comment: @SeanLange I found the error once I got rid of the try catch. It solved my issue. Thank you!

Comment: I think you have only delayed future errors. Using IDENT_CURRENT like this is going to bit you hard at some point. To be honest this entire procedure could be reduced to a simple insert statement. The variables in there just make my head swim. There are at least twice as many variables as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already insert a row into Orders you should pass in the values from that so you can leverage them in this procedure. You are passing in some of the information already. If you include OrderID and CompanyID this would be quite a bit simpler. Pretty sure you could simplify this whole thing to something along these lines. And don't forget to never, never, never have an empty catch.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[INSERT_ORDER_DETAILS]
(
    @Product_id int
    , @Quantity_ordered int
    , @Status varchar(10)
    , @OrderID int --You should be passing this in
    , @CompanyID int --You should be passing this in
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAILS
    (
        PRODUCT_ID
        ,PAYMENT_ID
        ,QUANTITY_ORDERED
        , [STATUS]
        ,MEASUREMENT_ID
        ,DISC_PER_ITEM
        ,DISC_AMT_PER_ITEM
        ,TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM
        ,TOTAL_WDISC_PER_ITEM
        ,PAYMENT_STATUS_ID
        ,COMPANY_ID
    )
    select @Product_id
        , 0
        , @Quantity_ordered
        , @Status       
        , p.MEASUREMENT_ID
        , 0.00
        , 0.00
        , p.TOTAL_COST * @Quantity_ordered
        , p.TOTAL_COST * @Quantity_ordered
        , 2
        , @CompanyID
    FROM PRODUCTs p
    WHERE p.Id = @Product_id
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! Although your comment about the Try Catch is what really helped me in solving my issue. I will try this stored procedure as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching your begin statements to properly nest them:

```
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SET NOCOUNT OFF; ...
```